# Xamarin Android Localization not working after publish to playstore

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, localization

I'm stuck in a localization problem.
In my Xamarib.Forms app you can easily change the language with a click, I used localization for it and assigned a new culture depends on which country button is clicked.
On my development mobile (android) localization works without any problems. No matter if debug or release. But when I publish my app to playstore, the localization returns just the default language.
I have tried a lot of different approaches. I set the resx files to "allways copy" and to "never", I add .dll and .resx to android properties -> not compress. I renamed my resx files from languages.en.resx to languages.en-US.resx.
But nothing seems to work.
Do you have any hints for me? I dont want to build a translation system on my own...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What tutorial are you following for localization? Also, without publishing to play store, if you just install your app directly FROM the archive you are about to submit, does localization work?

Comment: which language ?

Comment: @Saamer I followed this tut: https://mindofai.github.io/Implementing-Localization-with-Xamarin.Forms/

Comment: I publish my apps with Microsofts AppCenter, I will try if there sis a way to unstill the apk from there.

Comment: @Prateek the available languages at the moment are german and english

Comment: You should follow the MS Docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?pivots=windows  since the tutorial you’re following is old. Did you add the right attributes-NeutralResourcesLanguage?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define NeutralLanguageResource in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file

The default resx file should have been set to generate code and all other resx files to **No Code Generation**

Since you said it works locally in debug mode and release mode you can down apj from AppCenter and view its contents in Zip viewer application.

Make sure if you are using ProGuard it's not removing those files.

If nothing works you should reach out to AppCenter support team.